# Any problems with RPLIDAR's low scan rate?

Tags: ros, mapping, rplidar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey All,

I am considering getting an RPLIDAR for 3D mapping and navigation of an indoor environment using an autonomous UAV. The sensor has a much lower scan rate than most lidar systems I've used, 5.5 Hz compared to 40-50 Hz. Has this presented any issues to anyone?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229953/any-problems-with-rplidar%27s-low-scan-rate?/) by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on ROS Answers with karma: 955 on 2016-03-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've used one with a Turtlebot with quite satisfactory results, but that is only for 2D low speed applications. Moving around at 0.5m/s you don't really notice any issues, mapping and localization works really well. However, if you make sudden movements, especially rotation, I do notice that the scan data can't quite keep up. It seems to lag behind by a few degrees during rotation maneuvers. I really can't say how well it would work when moving at much higher speeds though.

There seem to be more sensors like RPLIDAR coming out, so you may have more options in the future for inexpensive Lidar sensors. There is currently a kickstarter campaign for something similar to RPLIDAR called [Sweep](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/scanse/sweep-scanning-lidar?ref=card).

---

Originally posted by [Steven_Daniluk](https://answers.ros.org/users/25049/steven_daniluk/) with karma: 606 on 2016-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on 2016-04-18**:
Thanks, I am using it for 3D mapping with a UAV. I've purchased one for now for making a proof of concept demonstration but will get a sensor with a higher scan frequency for the prototype.